# Sending sms and email on button click in android

Tags: android, email, android-intent, sms

I am developing a healthcare app for checking glucose levels and communicating to the doctor. It is supposed to send an email for each check and an additional sms if in emergency. The activity checks whether its an emergency and prompts an intent for sms. However, I cannot do both(sending sms and email) on one button click. It sends sms only if email client is inactive. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dude see this this is only for sms sending process in android http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android